# GitHub updates to .md widgets not visible on site

Tags: github, netlify

I’ve just started creating a personal website, using Hugo/Academic, Netlify CMS, and GitHub hosting. I edited the content in the various .md files under `/content/home/`, but these edits are not shown in the website, when I open it in a browser (even after I wait a while).

I also tried to get NetlifyCMS to let me edit all the various widgets using its GUI. Right now the only “Collections” I see in the CMS are the default ones: Authors,Posts,etc. If I edit content from there, the changes *are* seen on the website, so I tried to also add there other widgets from the Academic template (Experience, etc). However, I found no place in the site's source code (or in the Netlify CMS) where to edit that list of widgets.

On the other hand, I cannot anywhere in my github repository find text contained in the default content of these widgets, so clearly I was not updating content in the right place.